# On-demand synchronization to a blank cluster on same virtual linux host?

Tags: linux, synchronization

Here's what I need for creating a test server replicating the production one

1 Replicating over the prod server - apache configurations, websites data and Mysql databases.

2 Replicating configurations in transit(virtual host ips, dns naming, etc) so that it will gel in the test environment.

Any pointers ?

Thank you very much indeed

Amit

P.S If someone wants to help with the setup and script writing, please get in touch

Answer (score 0):

You just have to

1. Set up the replicate (once)
2. Write a synchronization script (each)

This script can copy source code with tools like *rsync*, and copy database content with *mysqldump*.

Comment: Thanks Coren, I'm familiar with rsync on a partial synchronization, not entire system. The pont where am stuck at is N2 in my question.

Comment: You could use config software like Puppet, Chef or CfEngine in order to do that